# vba run time error 91 using search and update command

Tags: vba

I am working with a code to update the data in database through userform. Its first part i.e. search data is working fine but second part i.e. update sometime it works fine but sometime it gives runtime error 91

need help

```
Private Sub cmd_Update_Click()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
'check for a Name number
If Trim(Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value) = "" Then
Me.TextBox_Search_Data.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please fill the data in search box"
Exit Sub
End If
Set ws = Worksheets("Employee Data")
With ws
r.Value = Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value
r.Offset(, 1).Value = Me.TextBox_EmployeeName.Value
r.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_FatherHusbandName.Value
r.Offset(, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox_Designation.Value
r.Offset(, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox_Category.Value


Me.TextBox_Search_Data.SetFocus
MsgBox "Data Updated Sucessfully"

'clear the data
Me.TextBox_EmployeeNumber.Value = ""
Me.TextBox_EmployeeName.Value = ""
Me.TextBox_FatherHusbandName.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox_Designation.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox_Category.Value = ""


End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is 'r' and where/how is it defined?

Comment: Your `Set ws = Worksheets("Employee Data")`, `With ws` and `End With` statements are redundant in your code - you never use the `With` block for anything, and you only use `ws` as the object of the redundant `With` block.

Comment: Try removing the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` statement - it doesn't seem to be needed within this code, and the fact that you don't reset it to `True` anywhere means that something important might be going unreported.

Comment: r is located at the top before starting the code as Dim r as range

Comment: yeah genius YowE3K this is but was creating hurdle. Now after removing Application.DisplayAlerts=False code is working fine

Comment: (a) Removing `Application.DisplayAlerts=False` won't make your code work if it wasn't already working - it will just allow various Excel messages to be displayed that you were previously suppressing.  (b) If `r` is declared at the top of your form's code module, then that gives it module-level scope and **could** be used in this subroutine.  But where is `r` being set?  It obviously isn't being set reliably, so that is the part of the code that needs to be fixed.  (Or possibly the logic is wrong and therefore it isn't always reaching the line that does the `Set r ` statement.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the sheet may not be getting set properly, and thus it can't use the object in order to update. See modified code below:

```
Private Sub cmd_Update_Click()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    'check for a Name number
    If Trim(Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value) = "" Then
        Me.TextBox_Search_Data.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please fill the data in search box"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Change ThisWorkbook to a different workbook variable as needed.

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Employee Data")  
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            If not r is Nothing Then
                With r
                    .Value = Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value
                    .Offset(, 1).Value = Me.TextBox_EmployeeName.Value
                    .Offset(, 2).Value = Me.TextBox_FatherHusbandName.Value
                    .Offset(, 3).Value = Me.ComboBox_Designation.Value
                    .Offset(, 4).Value = Me.ComboBox_Category.Value
                End With
           Else
               'This will run if r is not set to a range.
           End If
    Else
        'This will occur if the sheet isn't set properly.
    End If

    Me.TextBox_Search_Data.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Data Updated Sucessfully"

    'clear the data
    Me.TextBox_EmployeeNumber.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox_EmployeeName.Value = ""
    Me.TextBox_FatherHusbandName.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox_Designation.Value = ""
    Me.ComboBox_Category.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: @AtulKantGodiyal - you do realise, don't you, that this is functionally no different to your own code, other than checking for the existence of a sheet that your code doesn't even use.

Comment: @YowE3K I actually completely missed that since he is using r he shouldnt be using ws. He should be ensuring that r is set to something instead. I'll update the code to reflect this.

Comment: thanks for your efforts but the same problem is going on again when i click ed update button for third entry it again gave runtime error 91. Can you look over it again

Comment: @AtulKantGodiyal - if you answer the question that user3598756 asked (in the comments to your question), we will have a chance of solving your problem.

Comment: I have edited the code so it should now check to ensure that r is set to something, but as YowE3K and user have pointed out, you will want to ensure r is being set to something. If it is a variable existing within the global or userform environment it will need to be set properly. Otherwise, you will want to declare it and set it within the code above.

Comment: R is defined as range and is universal for all the code i.e. it will work as range for all other codes

Comment: @AtulKantGodiyal Can you show the code that is setting `r` - obviously it isn't being set correctly in all situations.  (What confuses me is that you imply that `r.Value = Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value` always works, but `r.Offset(, 1).Value = Me.TextBox_EmployeeName.Value` sometimes doesn't.)

Comment: Then what is likely happening is your r variable is somehow not set when this function is called. If it is a global variable then this can happen multiple ways. The edited code above should catch this (you can put some code within the else block to do whatever you'd like if this happens). I would recommend explicitly defining r within your code if possible though. Global variables can be unreliable.

Comment: I wonder if the `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` is masking something (outside of this code) that is causing `r` to not be set correctly.

Comment: i set r as Set r = Worksheets("Employee Data").Columns(2).Find(myfind) Now it is working

Comment: @AtulKantGodiyal - I assume `myfind` has been assigned the value `Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value`, which is why you thought that `r.Value = Me.TextBox_Search_Data.Value` was working but `r.Offset(, 1).Value = Me.TextBox_EmployeeName.Value` wasn't - setting `r.Value` equal to what was previously in the cell, or not setting it, ends up with the same result.